# Spotifyd in docker on Pi4

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, docker

Has anybody got spotifyd working in a docker on a Pi4? I tried https://hub.docker.com/r/ggoussard/spotifyd but it is not working.

Running ubuntu server `arch` reports aarch64. But only the armhf version works. Not getting any sound though.

Any help?

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/dtcooper/raspotify ?

Comment: Note the "Running ubuntu server" part

Comment: Sorry, don't know what you tried to tell me. I've read the three sentences. Now I know: you use an armv8 (aarch64, arm64) 64 Bit architecture. I would expect that on a Raspi4. The armv7 (armhf [hard float], arm32) version of the spotifyd docker image works but the arm64 version does not. Yes, that's possible, but I have no experience with spotifyd. The only thing I can do, is to give you an alternative I've read about. I also can't help you with the sound thing. There so many posibilities. Alsa not installed correctly, no access right to the `/dev/alsa` device from docker, program error, ....

Comment: "Raspotify works on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian" not Ubnutu Server

Comment: Ah, now I understand. What they mean is raspottyfy can easily be installled on raspbian. But they do not say, it doesn't run on ubuntu server. Your question was about a docker image for raspi 4. As long as you got docker (64 bit version) installed on ubuntu server the image should not be a problem. As I did not see any problem with installation I did not understand the comment. You see it is better to ask directly and not "sophisticated" ;-).